# I want that Background Image of div should keep changing automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

In school they taught only how to apply javascript to change bgcolor of body of our webpage. I want that Background Image of div should keep changing automatically when I mouseover the button or div content. What am I missing in my Code ?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<input type="button" name="b1" value="Change Image" onmouseover="f1()">
<script src="javascript1.js">
</script>
<br><br>
<div id="main">
<h1>Karan</h1>
<h1>Karan</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function f1()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout("f2()",1200);
}
function f2()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage = "url('http://gallery.onderhond.com/galleries/2009/santorini-towns/08.JPG')";
window.setTimeout("f3()",1200);
}
function f3()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout("f4()",1200);}
function f4()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage = "url('http://gallery.onderhond.com/galleries/2009/santorini-towns/08.JPG')";
window.setTimeout("f5()",1200);
}
function f5()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout("f6()",1200);}
function f6()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage = "url('http://gallery.onderhond.com/galleries/2009/santorini-towns/08.JPG')";
window.setTimeout("f7()",1200);
}
function f7()
{
document.getElementById(main).style.backgroundImage =  "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout("f1()",1200);
}
```

Comment: you can use this plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Simple-jQuery-Background-Image-Slideshow-with-Fade-Transitions-Background-Cycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of syntax and functional errors in here. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuv20q9a/) with them corrected.

First, you'll want to include your javascript file before your input that has the `onmouseover` attribute. If you don't load the javascript first, it won't know what `f1` is. (This is achieved in the fiddle by telling it to include the javascript in the `<head>`)

Next, you have some syntax errors in your javascript file. I have corrected them  here:

```
function f1()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout(f2,1200);
}
function f2()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://gallery.onderhond.com/galleries/2009/santorini-towns/08.JPG')";
window.setTimeout(f3,1200);
}
function f3()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout(f4,1200);
}
function f4()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://gallery.onderhond.com/galleries/2009/santorini-towns/08.JPG')";
window.setTimeout(f5,1200);
}
function f5()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout(f6,1200);}
function f6()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://gallery.onderhond.com/galleries/2009/santorini-towns/08.JPG')";
window.setTimeout(f7,1200);
}
function f7()
{
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage =  "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg')";
window.setTimeout(f1,1200);
}
```

The first thing is that you need quotes around `main` in your calls to `document.getElementById()`, or else it will be trying to find a variable called main, instead of looking for elements with id of 'main'.

The next issue is that you were passing a string to the `window.setTimeout()` function.

```
window.setTimeout("f2()", 1200);
```

Instead, you need to pass a reference to the function, like this.

```
window.setTimeout(f2, 1200);
```

With these fixes, the desired effect occurs. When you move your mouse over the button, it loads the first image as the background of your 'main' div, then will swap out the image every 1200 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `main` a string that is passed to `document.getElementById()`.

For instance:

```
document.getElementById("main")
```

Also I would either call `setInterval`, or I would use `setTimeout` recursively with an argument to your callback function that would keep track of what interval you're on ... The way you're structuring it right now is a little confusing, and it basically looks like all your functions will call at once 1200ms later, rather than getting the sequencing you're looking for.

For instance:

```
function change_image(num) {
    switch(num) {
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = /* something */
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = /* something else */
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = /* something else */
            break;
        /* cases 3-6 */
    };

    //this will cause num to repeat from 0-6
    setTimeout(change_image, 1200, (num + 1) % 7);
}

//make the initial call
setTimeout(change_image, 1200, 0);
```

Comment: I like the use of _modulus_ to set the interval value.

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten you code and keep it more concise by using `setTimeout` with a Self Executing Function and storing your image URLs in an array.

```html
<div id="switcher"></div>
```

```css
#switcher {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```js
var i = 0;
(function rotateBG() {

    var el = document.getElementById( 'switcher' );
    var images = [
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=1',
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=2',
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=3',
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=4'
        ];

    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[ i ] + ')';

    i++;

    if ( i === 4 ) {
      i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout( rotateBG, 1200 );

})();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ms46d65/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry hungerstar your code has some bad elements that I have to point out for others. it was the `var i` in global scope that shocked me into posting.

```
// Never ever use 'i' in the global scope it will cause all sorts of head aches
var i = 0;  // so wrong, please never do this in global scope. PLEASE!!!.

// Now you are starting the code without checking if everything is in place.. Dom could be busy???
// you are also adding to the global scope. Never add to the global scope unless you have been commanded by god him self.
(function rotateBG() {      
    var el = document.getElementById( 'switcher' );  // should not be getting an element every time you need it. Get it once only
    var images = [  // over 300 bytes to store a number you are already tracking.. This has to go.
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=1',
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=2',
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=3',
        'http://placehold.it/300x300&text=4'
        ];

    // appart from the array access all good.
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[ i ] + ')';

    // very slow way of doing a cycling counter;
    i++;
    if ( i === 4 ) {
      i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout( rotateBG, 1200 );

})();
```

To do the same thing and not leave anything in the global scope. Smaller safer faster and how it should be done.

```
window.addEventListener( // wait for DOM to do its thing.
    "load",
    function(){
        var imageTick = function(){ // function scope to load function
            imageSwitchingElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://placehold.it/300x300&text='+(imageCounter+=1)%4+')';
            setTimeout(imageTick,1200);
        }
        var imageCounter = 0;  // use closure vars in load function scope to keep data you need
        var imageSwitchingElement = document.querySelector('#switcher');    // get the element only once
        imageTick(); // start up the ticker.
    },
    false
);
```